# Why can an MVC controller not be found on a new computer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015, url-routing

We're working on a MVC project with C#.  When running it through Visual Studio, it works on my local machine but not on a coworker's machine.  On my, the URL shows as localhost:58669/Account/Login which goes to the login view as expected.  On my coworker's machine using the same code -- same web.config, global.asax, etc. -- this gives him a 404 not found found error.  We've found if he goes to localhost:58669/Account/Login/Account/Login, it works on his machine.  I've not seen this before and can't figure out what's happening since we have the exact same code.  Anyone have any ideas?

Here's the global.asax.cs file with the routing in it:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "AppStdApi",
            "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApi",
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Here's the solution's web properties showing the start page:

[image]

Comment: Is your IISExpress config the same on each machine?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure the IIS settings on your coworker's computer is the same as the on at your computer. If your web.config and global.asax is the same, then this should solve the problem.

Comment: Is that in the project's applicationhost.config file?  Ex. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyProject\.vs\config\applicationhost.config.

Comment: @boilers222 open IIS on your computer and check the configuration on the UI and then compare it against the configuration of your friend's computer's IIS.